# No external hard boot on raspberry pi

Tags: boot, usb, sd-card, ubuntu-mate

Raspberry Pi 3 is using the operating system Ubuntu mate16.04
I would like to use raspberry as an external hard drive without using sd card. 
Is there any way?
I installed the ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img

Comment: My Pi does not have any built in storage medium. I don't think what you are asking for is possible, at this time.

Comment: If you Boot the Pi in toram mode it should still work after the SD card is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to boot from a USB Mass Storage Device on a Raspberry Pi 3

- [How to boot from a USB Mass Storage Device on a Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot) and
- [Pi 3 booting part I: USB mass storage boot beta](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/pi-3-booting-part-i-usb-mass-storage-boot/)

Money quote:

> If you can’t boot from the MSD, then there are some steps that you can take to diagnose the problem. Please note, though, this is very much still a work in progress:
>
> 1. Format an SD card as FAT32
> 2. Copy the current next branch bootcode.bin from [GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/next/boot/bootcode.bin) onto the SD card
> 3. Plug it into the Pi and try again

Comment: I've already done it, but when I remove the sd card, the screen is black and nothing....

Comment: see https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-i-usb-mass-storage-boot/ (maybe a solution at then end of the page)

Comment: @Thomas: Looks like the essential parts are included (now).

Comment: I inserted the bootcode.bin file and tried to run it but it does not work. When I remove the sd card and insert the hard disk, it stops in rainbow screen....

Comment: I bricked a 3TB and a 4TB mechanical hard drive leaving them plugged into my Pi, If you use a mechanical drive with a Pi make sure it is totally shut down before adding or removing HDD's. I now prefer accessing the drives over the network rather than plugging them in.